# Error "[general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving ..."

Tags: objective-c, macos, arm, apple-m1, macos-monterey

I'm on macOS Monterey (12.0.1), not iOS, objective-c, XCode 13

I'm receiving this log message after building my app for arm64:

```
[general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x1dcb1c848) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.objects', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDictionary' (0x1dcaee5d0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.
```

Any idea what's causing this and how to get rid of it?

Edit: it seems to happen with every app compiled on arm64 starting with macOS Monterey. So it might be a generic apple bug

Comment: thats not a bug, it is a notice.  It even tells exactly whats up. NSString was allowed in NSDictionary without being explicit allowed. Meaning you may want to read what changed on decoding objects (NSKeyedUnarchiver).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @OI Sen it've had a closer look to the NSUnarchiver.
First of all NSKeyedUnarchiver should be allocated and initialized like this:

```
NSError* err;

NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:someData error:&err];
```

In my specific case I use NSSecure coding. Therefore you have to specify classes on decoding objects. In my case it looked like this

```
NSDictionary* someDict = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClass:[NSDictionary class] forKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
```

But the NSDictionary contained additional strings. That was the cause of the log message. By adding NSString to the decoded class list the error is gone.

```
NSDictionary* someDict = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClasses:[[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:@[[NSDictionary class],[NSString class]]] forKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
```

Comment: I've added same code still i am getting same error ?

Comment: You might have other objects inside nested or sub nested dictionaries, arrays...

Comment: NSError *error = nil;
    
    NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:encodedObject error:&error];

    
    NSSet *sets = [NSSet setWithArray: @[
        [NSMutableArray class],
        [NSDictionary class],
        [NSMutableDictionary class],
        [NSArray class],
        [NSDate class],
        [NSString class],
        [NSNumber class],
        [NSIndexSet class]]];
    
    id object  = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClasses:sets forKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];

Comment: I am using common function for encode and decode data , where result class will not fixed , it might array , dictionary , string , number so i have added set , what is wrong i am doing here ?

Comment: Do you have any custom object stored inside? E.g. inherited from NSObject that itself contains an encoding/decoding?

Comment: Yes i have custom classes too

Comment: Then you have custom encoders/decoders in these classes. You have to implement this all the way down in every class and subclass that's getting encoded/decoded.

Comment: But the project is 10year earlier and doing changes in all classes takes a lot of time , i need quick solution on this

Comment: Don't use secure coding then. Please open another thread for your issue. This is not the right place

Answer (score 2):

Another related situation is if you're using NSCoder.

This code generated the warning:

`self.expression = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey: kExpression];`

Warning eliminated with:

```
self.expression = [aDecoder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSString class] forKey:kExpression];
```

Note use of **decodeObjectOfClass:[NSString class]** instead of **decodeObjectForKey**.

Comment: NSUnarchiver basically uses decoder to decode nested objects...